# Battery case with data throughput

Tags: usb, android, smartphones, case, power-bank

I have a Nexus 5X, that I use to connect to my drone with the DJI Go app. I plug my phone into the drone's remote controller through the USB C port on my phone. (Same concept as plugging into a computer)
**I am looking for a case with a built in battery pack**.

- It has to support full data throughput
- Has to be able to charge my phone at the same time
- I would prefer larger than 2,000mAh
- I don't care about physical size, durability, color, price etc.

Comment: Can you please explain what you are looking for and how it interacts with the drone a bit more. I am having a hard time understanding what you are asking about. Are you just looking for a Nexus 5X phone case with a built in battery pack that still allows you to connect to a computer (for example) or is it more than that?

Comment: @Cfinley Yes I am looking for a Nexus 5X phone case with a built in battery pack that still allows you to connect to a computer

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! I do have a few more quick questions. How big should that battery pack be (in mAh)? Do you have a budget for this?

Answer (score 1):

Every battery case I've seen (for phones with non-removable batteries) occupies the port. Meaning that you can't use it for other interfaces. So that seems like an unlikely solution (not to say it isn't possible or doesn't exist). I realize this doesn't exactly match the criteria presented by the question, but please bear with me. **[What if you used a USB C Multiport Adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00VU2K10G)**? **[Along with a Male USB 3.0 to Female USB 3.1 adapter.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01ABTHI7C)** Apple's verison seems the most reputable (all the other manufacturers selling something similar on Amazon are companies I've never heard of). If it works with USB C on a [MacBook](http://www.apple.com/macbook/), then why shouldn't it work on a phone? ***All USB ports must meet a certain standard.***

--

**In Conclusion, You Could Do This:**

*Connect phone to multiport adapter.
Connected to the multiport adapter is  a USB 3.0 to USB C adapter (for connecting to your drone controller)
Connected to the USB C on the multiport adapter is a phone charger of somesort.*

--

### Can someone verify that this does work? It seems like it would work to me, considering the fact that the USB interface is standardized. Thanks!

Comment: This seems like a pretty bulky option for my scenario. Too many cords/adapters to get in the way...